# VMware Fusion virtual machine from a local partition

Tags: partition, vmware, virtualization

When you have a Windows partition on your system, VMware can see and boot a virtual machine from partition.

However, with other OS X and Linux partition, there's no such option. Is there a way to make a virtual machine and "link" the local partition?

Answer (score 2):

This guide appears to show how to do this.  Looks like there's some manual commands on the command line to create a vmdk file with a pointer to the raw device:

http://andrewfarley.com/mac/raw-disks-from-vmware-fusion

Comment: That link is no longer valid